# A modified version of log-sum inequality.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose $a_i>0, b_i>0, c_i>0 \; \forall i = 1, 2, \dots, n$, and

$$\sum_{i} a_i b_i \ln(\frac{c_i}{b_i}) \geq 0, $$

where $a_i, b_i, c_i$ are not constant over $i$. Moreover,

$$\sum_{i}a_ib_i\leq \sum_{i} c_i.$$

Under which conditions, the following would hold:

$$\sum_{i} b_i \ln(\frac{c_i}{b_i}) \geq 0.$$

Comment: The question as is seems too general. Let $c_i' = \ln(c_i/b_i)$; then $c_i > 0$ arbitrary is equivalent to $c_i' \in \mathbb{R}$ being arbitrary. You are assuming $\sum_i a_i b_i c_i' \ge 0$, and want some conditions for which $\sum_i b_i c_i' \ge 0$. This seems too general, since if for some $i$, $b_ic_i' > 0$, you can conceivably use a very big $a_i$ to force $\sum_i a_i b_i c_i' \ge 0$ to be true. It's not clear what constraints you may want to impose on $a_i$ without knowing your intended appilcation.

Comment: @dummy I edited the question a bit. I already know that $\sum_{i} a_i b_i \leq \sum_{i} c_i$. I guess now it is more meaningful, isn't it?

Comment: @dummy as for the intented application, I need it to prove something withing importance sampling context. A more detailed question is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4868751/maximizing-the-expectation-in-ce-importance-sampling?noredirect=1#comment10381067_4868751